# IIS websites stop responding and iisreset gives "The data is invalid. <2147942413, 8007000d>"

Tags: iis, iis-7, iisreset

**Question:**
What is the cause of the `The data is invalid. <2147942413, 8007000d>` error on an iisreset?

**Description:**
We had an issue with our IIS 7 webserver on Windows Server 2008 where a few clients received "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply..." error indicating they were probably queued before timing out.

For a quick workaround to bring the web service back up, we did an iisreset which failed with an error:

```
Restart attempt failed.
The data is invalid. <2147942413, 8007000d>
```

This has never happened before with this server.
Finally, we did a server restart and the web service was up and running again.

**What was tried?**
The following things were done before resorting to a server restart:

1. A backup of the applicationHost file was done to eliminate an IIS
   config corruption to be the cause. On comparing the backup with that
   of the current one after restart showed no difference.
2. Restarted the World Wide Web Publishing Service windows service and then did an iisreset but gave the same error. Pls note that an iisreset in
   turn stops and starts the World Wide Web Publishing Service. Tried both from the services.msc console and using `net stop` and `net start`.
3. Checked the CPU/RAM usage in Task Manager and nothing seemed
   abnormal
4. Checked the IIS log of that day u_xxxxxxx.log in the inetpub folder but there was nothing there to describe this error. Most of them with 200 status code and a few 401 status codes which I caused.

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer for anything abnormal?

Comment: There has been no events on Event Viewer related to this issue.

Comment: any applied updates or web.config changes?

Comment: Have you tried net stop iisadmin /y from the command prompt before IISReset.exe and to restart net start w3svc

Comment: For the restart, I'm curious on which user IIS is running as. If you start task manager, you should be able to locate it in the list. If running as system, you may need to use something like system internals to launch an elevated console to issue the restart. Perhaps there is a permissions issues with a file or something that gets locked, so the reboot of the system is needed. Trying the elevated restart may help remove the reboot need at least. Good luck at find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

What layer of your code would propagate an error to the client? If you are getting invalid data, then you must validate the data connected to the service. Garbage in garbage out I say. I would check your CRUD operations first and be sure that you aren't swallowing exceptions within your Channel Factory.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, **wait for up to 2 mins and try again**. Usually it should work after that. The cause behind this is because when you execute iisreset, it stops the app pools and then start again. While some of the app pool may be in use, it takes some time to completely stop and start again.
Hope it helps.